# Render h3 only if this type doesn't exist yet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am quite new to ruby and working on a project. I have a database of items that shows different products, links, and svg files. I keep it in a collection and loop through the items. For now, I only want to render a type name if it doesn't exist.

```
`<%= render partial: "site/main, collection: [
     {
        type: 'Garden',
        link: '/garden/pot',
        svg: '//images/pot.svg',
        name: 'Pot of your dreams',
        description: 'A perfect pot for any household'
    },
    {

        link: '/garden/flower',
        svg: '//images/flower.svg',
        name: 'A perfect flower',
        description: 'You need to buy it for your garden!'
    }
]`
```

I want to render the h3 only if it doesn't exist yet:
    `<h3><%=main[:type]%></h3>`
  So it is rendered only once, not all the time. There will be an h3 element rendering Garden only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach will be to group your collection by type. And then render collection within the type as another collection.

Here is what I mean(feel free to change the names):
After you regroup by collection type you'll get something like this(it may have a different format, but you'll get the idea):

```
collection = [
{ type: 'Garden', type_collection: [
     {
        link: '/garden/pot',
        svg: '//images/pot.svg',
        name: 'Pot of your dreams',
        description: 'A perfect pot for any household'
      },
      {
        link: '/garden/flower',
        svg: '//images/flower.svg',
        name: 'A perfect flower',
        description: 'You need to buy it for your garden!'
      }
    ],
  type: 'Type #2', type_collection: [
     {
        link: '/garden/flower2',
        svg: '//images/flower.svg',
        name: 'A perfect flower from type2',
        description: 'You need to buy it for your garden!'
      }
    ]
}]
```

then your site/main can have something like this:

```
<p>
  <h3><%= main[:type] %></h3>
  <%= render partial: 'site/type_collection', collection: main[:type_collection] %>
</p>
```

and your site/type_collection will have whatever you initially had:

```
<p>
  <%= type_collection[:link] %>
</p>
```

Comment: Let me know if you need help with grouping

Comment: thank you! I followed your advice and it was the solution I was looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

In your partial which renders items of the collection, you can generate h3 using [tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) helper

```
<%= tag.h3 item[:type].presence || main[:type] %>
```

assuming each item is in the collection is represented by locals `item`